# "<" sign in italics in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

I need to put expressions containing "<" and ">" sign in italics. For example, *GenericPositive*

However, when I do

```
\textit{GenericPositive<Type>}
```

it does not display the "<" or ">" signs. I also tried to add a slash so:

```
\textit{GenericPositive\<Type\>}
```

but it doesn't work either. What is more, I also tried the math mode with "$" signs so:

$GenericPositive$

and it does display the "<", ">" signs but then the whole expression gets split between different lines of text and I don't want that to happen.

What can I do to see "<" and ">" in an expression in italics in such a way that this expression is not split between different lines of text?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example (a full but minimal document we cqan copy and test as is). For me they appear if I add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to a super simple minimal doc

Comment: @daleif This solved the problem. Thank you so much

Comment: Do you really want the `<>` symbols in italics? I'd recommend using angle brackets, instead, and always upright.

Answer (score 4):

I take it that you use pdfLaTeX and the "original", aka `OT1`, font encodings.

I have two suggestions:

- If, for some reason, you can't or mustn't switch to the newer `T1` font encoding, you could write

  ```
  \textit{GenericPositive\textless Type\textgreater}
  ```
- As @daleif has already noted in a comment, the problem vanishes if you include the instruction

  ```
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  ```

  in the preamble.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want to typeset source code. If that is the case I would highly recommend to use a specialized package for that like [minted](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted). Please note that minted depends on python and pygments and therefore requires the `-shell-escape` flag as described in sections 2.1 and 3.1 of it's [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted).

I don't know what language you want to use so I am inserting a LaTeX example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\setminted{autogobble, breaklines}

\begin{document}
A block of code:
\begin{minted}{latex}
    \documentclass{beamer}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
        \uncover<+->{Hello}
        \uncover<+->{World}
    \end{center}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
\end{minted}

Or inline:
\mintinline{latex}{\uncover<+->{Hello}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify how your answer addresses the OP's stated objective, "I need to put expressions containing "<" and ">" sign in italics."